# Event "unchecked" induced in the same way how "checked"(which work) dont work. Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I dont understand why my event Unchecked isnt run. I have checkbox when I click it I change IsChecked = true in my all  data in datagrid. When i click button again i change IsChecked on false.

When I click first time i run my event Checked.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WordsDataGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="WordsDataGrid_CellEditEnding" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="X" Width="10" Binding="{Binding Status}">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnUnchecked"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Visibility="Visible" Height="16" Width="16" Click="UpdateOrAdd_Click">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image x:Name="KeyName"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}"  />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

private void All_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        words.ForEach(y => y.Status = true);
        RefreshDataGridWords();
    }

    private void All_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        words.ForEach(y => y.Status = false);
        RefreshDataGridWords();
    }

    private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
    private void OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

For me it is the same, but second dont run event.

This work when I do that:

```
 var itemsSource = WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<StatusWords>;
 foreach (var item in itemsSource)
 {
     item.Status = true;
 }
 RefreshDataGridWords();

 private void RefreshDataGridWords()
 {
     WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
     WordsDataGrid.ItemsSource = words;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `RefreshDataGridWords` in the event handlers? This shouldn't be needed provided that you have raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of `Status`.

Comment: I was trying and without dont work for both and when I use IList it dont work to for both.

Comment: `IList`? What do you mean? Please provide a minimal and reproducible example when you ask a question. This code sample makes no sense. There should be no reason to reload the `DataGrid`.

Comment: I add solution. Nevertheless, I do not understand why then it worked for only one event.

Comment: Me neither based on the (lack of) information you have provided.

Comment: I think it was enough, because it didnt do more then set status in list<object> for true or false and refresh grid. And it was work for Checked, but for Unchecked didnt.

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Did you place a break point to actually see if it gets called?